# Facing Issue while merging two variable result sets in BPEL 2.0

Tags: bpel, xpath-2.0

I am facing issue while merging the response of two variable (holding and list of objects) in BPEL 2.0

My code snippet is as below:

```html
<assign name="AssignJobList">
          <extensionAssignOperation>
            <bpelx:copyList>
              <bpelx:from>$InvokeJobDetailsPSGetUpdatedJobObjectsResponse.JobProxyResponse/sfabmabo:Job</bpelx:from>
              <bpelx:to>$MergeJobListResponseMessage.JobProxyResponse/sfabmabo:Job</bpelx:to>
            </bpelx:copyList>
            <bpelx:insertAfter>
              <bpelx:from>$InvokeJobDetailsPSGetEffectiveJobObjectsResponse.JobProxyResponse/sfabmabo:Job</bpelx:from>
              <bpelx:to>$MergeJobListResponseMessage.JobProxyResponse/sfabmabo:Job[last()]     </bpelx:to>
     </bpelx:insertAfter>
  </extensionAssignOperation>
</assign>
```

For the CopyList operation, its is updating the target to variable but for the insert after operation one neither its merging nor its throwing an error.

Could you please help me in the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above issue can be resolved by adding a tag  for each bpelx operation as shown below:

```html
<assign name="AssignUpdatedandMergedJobList">
  <extensionAssignOperation>
    <bpelx:copyList>
      <bpelx:from>$InvokeJobDetailsPSGetUpdatedJobObjectsResponse.JobProxyResponse/sfabmabo:Job</bpelx:from>
      <bpelx:to>$MergeJobListResponseMessage.JobProxyResponse/sfabmabo:Job</bpelx:to>
    </bpelx:copyList>
  </extensionAssignOperation>
  <extensionAssignOperation>
    <bpelx:insertAfter>
      <bpelx:from>$InvokeJobDetailsPSGetEffectiveJobObjectsResponse.JobProxyResponse/sfabmabo:Job</bpelx:from>
      <bpelx:to>$MergeJobListResponseMessage.JobProxyResponse/sfabmabo:Job[last()]</bpelx:to>
    </bpelx:insertAfter>
  </extensionAssignOperation>
</assign>
```

Regards,